# Could not build wheels for contourpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, shared-hosting

I was installing `contourpy` library in my shared hosting server, and I encountered the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for contourpy
Failed to build contourpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for contourpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I talked to my hosting provider and they said it will be the best to consider VPS and shared server has some technical conflicts. What should I do to install this library?

Comment: Is your pip up to date?

Comment: yes, pip is up to date

Comment: Please [edit] to provide information about your hosting provider's environment: OS, distribution, Python version, what command did you use to install, etc.